# Swagger .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to configure swagger for my .Netcore App (1.1) and couldnt generate the docs.

Here is my configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddMvcCore().AddVersionedApiExplorer(o => o.GroupNameFormat = "1.0");
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
            {

                opt.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version");
                opt.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
                opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            });
    services.AddSwaggerGen(
                options =>
                {
                    options.SwaggerDoc("1.0",new Info {Contact = new Contact() {Name="Admin" } });
                    // add a custom operation filter which sets default values
                    options.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
                });
}
```

In the Configure Method

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=User}/{action=Get}/{requestString?}");
            });

            app.UseSwagger(o=>
            {
                o.RouteTemplate = "docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";

            });
            app.UseSwaggerUI(
                options =>
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/1.0/swagger.json", "1.0");
                });
```

When I run the application, 
`http://localhost:5000/docs/1.0/swagger.json`

I am getting the below methods, None of my API's are discovered.

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"contact":{"name":"Admin"}},"basePath":"/","paths":{},"definitions":{},"securityDefinitions":{}}
```

Comment: 1. Are you using the same [SwaggerDefaultValues](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample/SwaggerDefaultValues.cs) filter? If no, please share it.

Comment: @Set, I was following this sample to setup swagger https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample/Startup.cs

I have set up the SwaggerDefaultValues filter.

Comment: I did comment the addMvc and configured my code to use addMVCCore and still I have the same issue

    `services.AddMvcCore().
                AddControllersAsServices().
                AddJsonFormatters().
                AddJsonOptions(opt=>
                { 
                    if (opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver != null)
                    {
                        opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                    }
                }).
                AddVersionedApiExplorer(o => o.GroupNameFormat = "1.0");`

Comment: regarding using both `AddMvcCore ` and `AddMVC`  I was wrong. See answer in [Swagger sample. Why MVC services are registered twice?](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have reproduced your problem and found that the reason is the value in `GroupNameFormat` option.

If quickly, instead of const version string you should specify `version format`. As you want to have version in url as `1.0` you may use:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddVersionedApiExplorer( o => o.GroupNameFormat = "VVVV" );
```

From [Version Format](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Version-Format#custom-api-version-format-strings) section in Documentation:

> Format Specifier: `VVVV`
>
> Description: Major, minor version, and status
>
> Examples: 1-RC -> 1.0-RC, 1.1 -> 1.1, 1 -> 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `AddMvcCore()` vs `AddMvc()`:

From the swagger docs at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

> Swashbuckle relies heavily on ApiExplorer, the API metadata layer that ships with ASP.NET Core. If you're using the AddMvc helper to bootstrap the MVC stack, then ApiExplorer will be automatically registered and SB will work without issue. However, if you're using AddMvcCore for a more paired-down MVC stack, you'll need to explicitly add the Api Explorer service:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();
```

If you also want `AddVersionedApiExplorer()`, chain that after `AddApiExplorer()`